# Show div only when dropdown is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, visibility, show-hide

I need a specific div to only be visible when a specific dropdown is open. The closest I can get is having the div show on change, but this isn't what I need. When the dropdown is closed, the div should hide along with it, so binding of sorts? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/v2JSN/

**HTML**

```
    <select class='ddInfo'> 
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
        <option>option 3</option>
    </select> 


<div class='info'>
    only showing while dropdown is open
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.ddInfo').change(function(){
    $('.info').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the focusOut event in jQuery combined with the click event.

```
$('.ddInfo').on('click', function () {
    $('.info').show();
```

});

```
$('.ddInfo').on('focusout', function () {
    $('.info').hide();
});
```

Example in fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2JSN/6/)

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly, even with the widget I'm using.

Comment: It's working in Chrome for me? One more thing. Can we have the div visible if the user is hovering over it, or focused on it?

Answer (score 0):

This works on fiddle, works fine even when option is selected

```
$('.ddInfo').click(function(){
    $('.info').toggle();
});

$('.ddInfo').blur(function(){
    $('.info').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r47kK/1/

EDIT check the updated fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/r47kK/3/

```
$('.ddInfo').click(function(){
    $('.info').toggle();
});

$('.ddInfo').hide(function(){
    $('.info').toggle();
});
```